# Handle details tag and checkbox click event with Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

How I can prevent that a Checkbox or button element that is on the same height (dom level) as a details element triggers the event to expand or collapse the details element?

```html
<details>
<summary>
   Click on checkbox <input type='checkbox'/> 
   or buttons
   <button type="button">PDF</button>
   <button type="button">Picture</button>
   <button type="button">Foo</button> </summary>
<p>This shouldn't be visible :( </p>
</details>
```

Comment: @TimSch what JS and why he need to add JS, this a CSS question

Comment: @TimSch I invite you then to read about the details/summary tag

Comment: @matthis, what browser are you using, because the click on the element is no triggering the expand/collapse

Comment: @TemaniAfif wow you are right. On Google Chrome it works fine. I'm using Firefox. Nice hint! :)

Comment: Anyways on Firefox this is broken the content shouldn't be displayed when clicking on a button.

Comment: This bug is fixed in Firefox 67. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1524893